# What is the difference between a callback function, helper function and wrapper function?

Tags: javascript

I have been doing extensive research on google but I still cannot find my answer. From what I understand, a helper function is a function which helps reduce the complexity of some computation by providing a name for a part of the computation and the ability to take arguments. From the few codes I've seen, so do the other two functions...

Comment: [callback function](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced) commonly found in asynchronous code and [wrapper function](https://blog.sentry.io/2016/02/03/wrap-javascript-functions) often to do with closures - using google to research either of those phrases results in a ton of information, most of it good

Comment: And what about helper function?

Comment: A helper function is often used to prevent code reputation. In other languages these are mostly the private methods of a class.

Comment: Well that's described adequately in the question don't you think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to try to keep the terminologies and buzzwords down seeing that most beginners struggle to grasp new concepts because they go down a terminology rabbit hole.

**Callback functions** contain code you want an underlying subsystem to execute after it completes a specific task that is not sequential in nature. The subsystem is usually an abstraction for something happening under the hood and exposes an API for you to use which accepts the function. Think of it like sending a one-way message to someone/something to help you complete a task with no guaranteed ETA and then leaving a number/address they could reach you when the task is done. This is a concept that is natural to languages that accept functions as data.

**Helper functions** basically contain required "detour" code that helps with separating concerns. A function reads better when you make it do one thing well. If your function is doing too much then you might want to carefully think about what you are trying to accomplish and the steps to get you there. For example, say you have some code that needs to calculate the price for delivering a package from point A to B, part of that task also involves calculating the distance between two points. You don't want business code mixed up with your cryptic Haversine formula code, do you? In this case, your Haversine formula calculation can be a helper function. Helpers can also help with code reuse if they need to be used in more than one place in your project.

**Wrapper functions** let you wrap complex or foreign code in order to achieve some goal. That goal could be to expose a different set of interface, hide complexity or execute some code before and/or after calling the underlying function by way of proxy. When one function A calls another function B, A is said to have wrapped B.

Hope that helps.